# Ubuntu 14.04 server: Change em1 to eth0 - no /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules file

Tags: ubuntu, networking, udev, interface

I am trying to rename one of my network interfaces from `em1` to `eth0`. I do not have /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules. I have tried to regenerate this file by running these commands:

```
udevadm trigger
udevadm trigger --action=add
udevadm trigger --action=change
```

I tested each command individually, rebooted, looked for the 70-persistent file, before trying the next. None of the commands work, as the file is still not there, even after reboot.

I have also tried manually running the /lib/udev/write_net_rules and I get this error:

```
Cannot lock /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules!
```

This is what is in my /etc/network/interfaces file (nothing else):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

My ifconfig output results in no eth0 interface, but I have an em1 interface that I need to change to eth0. I don't know how to do this without re-creating the 70-persistent file. Any help in either recreating this file or changing em1 to eth0, or both, would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: After a small troubleshooting session with OP I'm modifying the answer to remove the quotes for "biosdevname"

Edit the following lines in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

To:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=biosdevname=0
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=biosdevname=0
```

Next, run `sudo update-grub` and then reboot.

After this, you should have the `udev` rules persisted in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and you can edit them as necessary.

Make sure you're changing the right interface by comparing MAC address information properly, e.g. via `ifconfig -a`.

Comment: When I add that to grub and run ```sudo update-grub``` I get the error: ```biosdevname=0: not found```. Am I missing a package or other file?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install biosdevname` and then run `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Comment: That did not work, I still get the same error. In full it is : ```/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 12: /etc/default/grub: biosdevname=0: not found```

Comment: And this is after you ran `sudo apt-get install biosdevname` and then `sudo update-initramfs - u` ?

Comment: Yes. Do I need to reboot after running ```sudo update-initramfs - u``` and then do ```sudo update-grub`` and reboot again?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to reboot after installing biosdevname and updating the initramfs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27068/discussion-between-john-jensen-and-lchristina26).

Comment: This solution worked, thanks John Jensen!